# PHP 7.0 and 7.1 PDF error with Craft Commerce orders

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, dompdf

Switching over to a new server and using PHP 7.0 (and 7.1) everything looked to be fine until I tried to view an order PDF within an email from Craft Commerce. Even using the email template provided by the plugin. The error is:

```
No block-level parent found. Not good.
```

I can't remember which DOM-PDF issue thread I came across it in, but the solution is to remove

```
<head></head>
```

from the document. Does anyone know of a more elegant solution? I don't think it's my server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across the same issue yesterday. After a bit of reading and trial and error I found the most elegant way for now is to remove the white space between these elements.

`<html><head>
</head><body>
</body></html>`

Personally I achieved this by adding comments `<!--  -->` between to remove the white space

`<html><!--
--><head>
</head><!--
--><body>
</body><!--
--></html>`

I piked this up from this thread initially. 
https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/issues/389

I think that the proper solution might be to enable the html5 parser, but I think this might be a config setting within the DomPDF? Would this fall ino the Craft Commerce files?

`"enable_html5_parser" => true,`

Comment: I set tried both of those and had no success. I set "enable_html5_parser" within dompdf inside Craft Commerce and even created a template with zero whitespace!

Comment: In the end, I've gone with your solution but without comments. It seems it's just having no whitespace before <head> and after </head> that works for me, so that was easy enough.

Separately, I then found an issue with <thead> and <tbody> elements no longer being supoported. So I've taken them out as well.

Answer (score 2):

This should be fixed as of Commerce 1.2.1354

https://craftcommerce.com/changelog#build1354